# Find the interval in which $\int_{-1}^{x} (e^{t} -1)(2-t) dt , (x>-1)$.

Tags: calculus

> Find the interval in which $F(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} (e^{t}-1)(2-t) dt$ , $(x>-1)$ is increasing.

By solving integral
$$\int_{-1}^{x} ((2-t)e^{t} -2 +t)dt 
= [(2-t)e^{t} + e^{t} -2t + t^{2}/2]_{-1}^{x}$$
and this gives me
$$3e^{x} -xe^{x} -2x + x^{2}/2 - 4/e - 5/2$$
now, i don't know how to proceed. 
I don't how to find roots so that i can get the interval.

Is there some easy way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that by the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) the derivative of $F$ is the integrand function
$$f(x)=(e^x-1)(2-x),$$
so in order to find the interval where $F$ is increasing, it suffices to discuss the sign of $f$.

Comment: Oh yeah, by applying leibnitz rule, I am getting this.The roots of derivative are $0$ and $2$. And the interval is $[0,2]$. Thanks.